# Prove that there exists a path between two vertices such that length of path is less than equal to n-1

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

It is stated that path exists between two vertices.

My idea is that if there is a direct path from source to vertex then the length is 1 which is less than n. But we need the minimum path to be as maximum as possible to disprove the statement.
So we include as many vertices as possible in the path. The maximum can be n. If all n are included in the path, then a simple path would have n-1 length. We can't go any longer than that. So, it is proved. 
Can you help me present this formally? And also please correct any mistakes I may have in my idea.

n is the number of vertices.

Comment: To prove it formally, argue that at any step of the path you should end at a node where you haven't been before.

Comment: @Henrik But that's not a condition. That is true for "simple path" not for just "path". Probably showing that if a path exists then a simple path also exists and then doing the argument that you mention might work. Is it enough to say that `"Since, a path exists between the two vertices, a simple path also exists and it is the path with minimum length"`?

Comment: @bof yes your guess is correct. As far as P is concerned, nothing what we have seen in the past helps us to go forward, so if we are back at a vertex to take a new edge, then we could have taken it at the first chance itself. So, yeah we shouldn't see a vertex twice. Is such a statement enough to establish the fact that we shouldn't see old vertex again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a $u,v$-path, then there is a $u,v$-path of shortest possible length, equal to the distance from $u$ to $v.$ Let $P$ be such a path. Clearly, if $P$ repeated a vertex, then we could make a shorter $u,v$-path, which is absurd. Hence $P$ is a simple path. If $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph, then $P$ is a simple path containing at most $n$ vertices, so the length of $P$ is at most $n-1.$